# Problema con agregar icono a formularios en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy teniendo un inconveniente a la hora de ponerle íconos a los **formularios** de mi aplicación hecha en `C#` con `WinForms` **(VisualStudio 2022)** y es que cada vez que intento compilar me sale el siguiente error:

> No se puede procesar el archivo Form1.resx porque está en Internet o en una zona restringida, o bien tiene la marca de la Web. Quite esta marca si desea procesar los archivos.

Intenté añadiendo los archivos **.ico** al proyecto y sucede lo mismo. Intenté poniéndolos en el escritorio y sucede lo mismo. Los archivos **.ico** los probé con las distintas medidas **(16x16/32x32/64x64)** y ninguno funciona. Siempre sale el mismo error, una vez que quito ese archivo **.ico** vuelve a compilar sin problemas. Adjunto imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso he probado creando una carpeta **Images** dentro del proyecto y añadiendo los **.ico** dentro pero tampoco ha funcionado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El **.ico** no está bloqueado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien tendrá idea de cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Has probado a incluirlo en: *click derecho en proyecto/Pestaña Aplicacion/Recursos Icono y Manifiesto* y seleccionar el icono ahí?

Comment: no estaría viendo esa sección que me decís. Es decir, no veo por ningún lado que diga Aplicacion dentro de Proyecto

Comment: perdon, me falto poner Propiedades, la ruta completa seria *click derecho en proyecto/click propiedades/Pestaña Aplicacion/Recursos Icono y Manifiesto*

Comment: Entonces, sí. HIce exactamente lo que mencionas y tampoco me funcionó. Seguía saliendo el mismo error

Comment: es por que tu archivo esta en una carpeta en red, copia todo el proyecto con imagenes a una carpera local y debe de funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue hacerlo programáticamente:

```
    private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Icon = new Icon(@"C:\Ruta\Del\Archivo\logo.ico");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

### **Variante 1**

**1)** Cierra el **Visual Studio** en caso de tenerlo abierto.

**2)** Abre el **explorador de Windows** y navega hacia la carpeta donde esta tu proyecto, busca alli todos tus ficheros con extension ***.resx** y ve uno por uno haciendo clic derecho y seleccionando la opcion propiedades y marcando la **opcion desbloquear** para cada fichero con extension ***.resx** (Que en tu caso quiza sea nada mas el fichero **Form1.resx**, ya que es el que te da error).

**3)** Vuelve a abrir el **Visual Studio**.

**4)** Por si acaso una vez que hayas abierto de nuevo tu proyecto, ve a tu **explorador de soluciones** clic derecho sobre tu proyecto y seleccionas la **opcion rebuild**.

**Nota:** Fijate bien que esta variante es con los ficheros de extension ***.resx**.

### **Variante 2**

Otra variante podria ser editar tus **ficheros** ***.ico**(yo uso una herramienta que se llama **IcoFXPortable**, tambien podrias usar el **Photoshop**), abririas tus **ficheros** ***.ico** con una de estas herramientas de edicion e irias a la **opcion Salvar Como**, entonces bien podrias guardar sobreescribiendo tu **fichero** ***.ico** o dandole otro nombre, siendo esta edicion del **fichero** ***.ico** la que usarias en tu proyecto.

### **Variante 3**

Dentro del **Visual Studio** ve al **menú Herramientas/Opciones/Configuración de confianza** y agregue la ruta del proyecto como una ruta de confianza.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### **Variante 4**

Ve a la ruta donde esta tu proyecto, y abre tu **fichero** ***.resx** que tiene problemas copia todo su contenido y borra este fichero. Despues crea un nuevo fichero de texto pega ahi el contenido previamente copiado y salvalo con el mismo nombre y extension del fichero que previamente habias borrado. Despues abre el **Visual Studio** y dale **rebuild** a tu proyecto.

### **Variante 5**

**1)** Abre el **menú Inicio** y escribe **'Internet Options'**.

**2)** En la ventana que se abre ve a la **pestaña Seguridad** y selecciona la **opción Local Intranet** y da clic en el **botón Sites**.

**3)** Posteriormente da clic en el **botón Advanced.**

**4)** Especifica el fichero a desbloquear: **fichero://[nombre computadora]**

**5)** Asegúrate de que el **checkbox 'Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone'** está desmarcado.

**Referencias:**

https://qastack.mx/programming/51348919/couldnt-process-file-resx-due-to-its-being-in-the-internet-or-restricted-zone-o

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/trust-settings?view=vs-2022

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/couldnt-process-file-abcresx-due-to-its-being-in-t/291761

Comment: Todo lo que mencionaste, ya lo había probado y hecho. Incluso en mi pregunta se ve que el Form.resx no tiene la opción de **desbloquear**, los archivos **.ico** fueron hechos por mi con **Photoshop**

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo revisa lo nuevo q puse

Comment: Sigue igual, no ha funcionado

Comment: Vuelve a revisar lo nuevo que puse

Comment: No me vas creer, sigue igual. Ya he probado todo

Comment: Uff, mira te recomiendo q pruebes en otra PC, la variante 3 que te explico es la q mas pinta tiene de funcionar, estas seguro que no te falto nada, a veces el cansancio nos hace confundirnos

Comment: Vuelve a revisar

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo resolviste algo?